# error: 8.13802e+06 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned char'

Tags: c, runtime, blur, cs50

close to the finish I've encountered a problem I can't solve. Maybe one of you can:

The compiling of the following code works fine but when I fire the program I get this error message:

helpers.c:228:42: runtime error: 8.13802e+06 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned char'

The code is a function to blur an image blockwise, but the very first pixel [0][0] does not get a correct average value and I don't know why I get that error message instead.

```
    // Blur image
    void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int m;
        int n;
        int averageRed;
        int averageBlue;
        int averageGreen;
        RGBTRIPLE average[height][width];




// For each row of the image...
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //...take each pixel.
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)


                //If current height equals 0 AND current width equals 0..   
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                {   
                    //..take 2 rows of the picture..
                    for (m = i; m <= i + 1; m++)
                    {   
                        //..and take 2 pixels of each row.
                        for (n = j; n <= j + 1; n++)
                        {
                        //Sum up the rgb-values for each of the 2 pixel of the 2 rows.
                        averageRed = averageRed + image[m][n].rgbtRed;
                        averageGreen = averageGreen + image[m][n].rgbtGreen;                                        
   -> The error line averageBlue = averageBlue + image[m][n].rgbtBlue;
                        }
                    }
                    //Save the average of the values in a separate array after the 2x2 pixel-block
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed = round((float)averageRed / 4);
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float)averageGreen / 4);
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((float)averageBlue / 4);

                    //Set average-variables to 0
                    averageRed = 0;
                    averageGreen = 0;
                    averageBlue = 0;
                }


        //From each row of the image...
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            //...take each pixel..
            for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                //...and update the original value with the temporary stored value.
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = average[i][j].rgbtRed;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: Too much code. See [mre]. Expecting us to wade through that much code isn't reasonable.

Comment: Sorry..  I hope it is not too short now

Comment: You never initialize or reset your `avarageRed` etc. to zero, so you get the infamous "garbage value", in your case 8.13802e+06.

Comment: How do you get a runtime error for range? Also `i` and `j` are uninitialised.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to insert the for-loops with the i and j initialization..

@ M Oehm: I do...  se below the error line "Set average-variables to 0". And everything else works fine. The only problem is the marked "averageBlue"

Comment: Yes, but you do that as "cleaning up" afterwards, so that the next pass has clean values. What I said is still true for te first pass, on which you get te error. Defining `int X;` as non-static variable in a routine will not initialize it to zero.

Comment: (For what it's worth, catching the (literal) corner cases here with repeated code in the innermost loop looks very prone to error. I'd calculate the ranges, adjust the bound s necessary and then keep a count of pixels you have considered. That sould get you down to a single case.)

Comment: Thank you very much M Oehm! That was indeed the problem. Could you explain me why  the issue was just with the averageBlue? The others should have been affected also, shouldn't they?

Comment: When you don't initlaize the variable, its value is indeterminate. It might well be zero or a small integer where the problem doesn't show.

Comment: @M Oehm: Bear with me, I'm a beginner ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another facepalm-answer :-)..

The solution was quite simple. It was just the missing initialization of the averageRed/Green/Blue-variables.

Didn't get it because the error message pointed only to the averageBlue.

Thanks to M Oehm again :-)